# Material UI React Table onCellClick

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I am trying to implement a simple onCellClick listener on Material UI table.

In earlier versions of it, a function in the table scope `onCellClick` used to give the row and column number where click was made as shown [here](https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/pull/7014)

Currently when this function is placed -

```js
import React from 'react';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import { withStyles } from '@material-ui/core/styles';
import Table from '@material-ui/core/Table';
import TableBody from '@material-ui/core/TableBody';
import TableCell from '@material-ui/core/TableCell';
import TableHead from '@material-ui/core/TableHead';
import TableRow from '@material-ui/core/TableRow';
import Paper from '@material-ui/core/Paper';

const styles = {
  }
let id = 0;
function createData(name, calories, fat, carbs, protein) {
  id += 1;
  return { id, name, calories, fat, carbs, protein };
}

const rows = [
  createData('Frozen yoghurt', 159, 6.0, 24, 4.0),
  createData('Ice cream sandwich', 237, 9.0, 37, 4.3),
  createData('Eclair', 262, 16.0, 24, 6.0),
  createData('Cupcake', 305, 3.7, 67, 4.3),
  createData('Gingerbread', 356, 16.0, 49, 3.9),
];

function SimpleTable(props) {
  const { classes } = props;

  return (
    <Paper className={classes.root}>
      <Table className={classes.table} 
      onCellClick={(rowNumber, 
      columnId) =>
       console.log(rowNumber,columnId)}>
        <TableHead>
          <TableRow>
            <TableCell>Dessert (100g serving)</TableCell>
            <TableCell numeric>Calories</TableCell>
            <TableCell numeric>Fat (g)</TableCell>
            <TableCell numeric>Carbs (g)</TableCell>
            <TableCell numeric>Protein (g)</TableCell>
          </TableRow>
        </TableHead>
        <TableBody>
          {rows.map(row => {
            return (
              <TableRow key={row.id}>
                <TableCell component="th" scope="row">
                  {row.name}
                </TableCell>
                <TableCell numeric>{row.calories}</TableCell>
                <TableCell numeric>{row.fat}</TableCell>
                <TableCell numeric>{row.carbs}</TableCell>
                <TableCell numeric>{row.protein}</TableCell>
              </TableRow>
            );
          })}
        </TableBody>
      </Table>
    </Paper>
  );
}


export default withStyles(styles)(SimpleTable);
```

it throws the error Unknown event handler property `onCellClick`. It will be ignored.This is expected because unlike previous versions no onCellClick function is passed in the table [source code](https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/blob/master/packages/material-ui/src/Table/Table.js).

How to achieve onCellClick functionality now in Material-UI?

Any help will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

A cell can be a `th` or `td` element ([see the source code](https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/blob/master/packages/material-ui/src/TableCell/TableCell.js#L112-L116)) or a custom element that you pass through the `component` property.

Each of these will have support for the [`onClick` property](https://reactjs.org/docs/events.html#mouse-events).

So you need something like this:

```js
handleClick = (id, column) => {
  return (event) => {
    console.log(`You clicked on row with id ${id}, in column ${column}.`);
  }
}

render() {
  return (
    // ...
    {this.state.rows.map((row) => (
      <TableRow key={row.id}>
        <TableCell onClick={this.handleClick(row.id, "calories")}>
          {row.calories}
        </TableCell>
        // ...
        <TableCell onClick={this.handleClick(row.id, "protein")}>
          {row.protein}
        </TableCell>
      </TableRow>
    )}
    // ...
  );
}
```